# Scala Type mismatch, expected: List[Double], actual: List[Any]

Tags: scala, generics, types

```
object lab3zad4 extends App{


val l1 = List(2.0, -1.6, 3.2, 5.4, -8.4)
val l2 = List(3.3, -3.1, 3.2, -4.1, -0.4, 5.5)
val wyn = max(l1,l2,Nil).toString

wyn.foreach(println)


def max(l1: List[Double], l2: List[Double], wyn:List[Double]) : List[Double] = {
 if(l1.isEmpty)
   wyn ::: l2
 if(l2.isEmpty)
   wyn ::: l1
// if(l1.nonEmpty && l2.nonEmpty)
  max(l1.tail,l2.tail, wyn :: help(l1.head,l2.head) :: Nil)


def help(x:Double, y:Double): Double = {
 if(x >= y)
   x
 else
   y

}
}
}
```

The mismatch seems to be caused by this line

```
 max(l1.tail,l2.tail, wyn :: help(l1.head,l2.head) :: Nil)
```

When I remove Nil from that line the problem seems to disappear but I cannot use :: to create the new list.
What do I do wrong?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The final statement (expression) of a method is what it returns. So move `help()` to the top of `max()`, not the bottom.
2. Use `else` to turn those `if` checks into a single statement of `if (..)` ... `else if (..)` ... `else` ...
3. `::` is used to *prepend* an element to the head of a `List`. If you need to *append* an element to the end of a `List` use `:+` (very inefficient on a `List`).

```
else max(l1.tail,l2.tail, wyn :+ help(l1.head,l2.head))
```

4. If you turn the result of `max(l1,l2,Nil)` into a `String` then you won't want to `foreach(println)` over it. That will `println` each character of the `String`.

Comment: I have used     wyn.foreach(print)       to print out the outcome

Comment: `println(wyn)` is shorter, clearer, and more efficient.

Comment: Why? is it better?

Comment: `"abcde".foreach(print)` invokes the `print()` method 5 times, once for every character of the `String`, whereas `println("abcde")` invokes the `println()` method just once.

Answer (score 2):

You turn `Double` to `String` here:

```
val wyn = max(l1,l2,Nil).toString
```

then you try to prepend it to the `List[Double]`

```
//                               List[Nothing]
//                                   \/
//
//         ------ List[Double] --------
//         \/                        \/
//  ---------- List[Any] --------------
//  \/                               \/
    wyn :: help(l1.head,l2.head) :: Nil
// String         Double            Nil
```

so Scala has to infer the result type to be `List[Any]`, while `max` function expects `List[Double]`.

Long story short, don't call `toString` on `wyn`.